# Ccxt binance fetchOHLCV doesn't return last data

Tags: python, binance, ccxt, ohlcv

I am using ccxt library for binance. To calculate the sar indicator, I am using fetchOHLCV to get last last historical data but the problem is that some times data are not reflecting the last binance data. We observe some delays
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
exchange = ccxt.binance({"apiKey": api_key,"secret": api_secret,'enableRateLimit': True})
pair = 'ETH/USDT'
timeframe='1m'
exchange.fetch_ohlcv(coin_pair, timeframe,limit=1000)
```